# linear velocity conversion problem

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

A ford  F-$150$ comes standard with tires that have a diameter of $25.7$ inches. If the owner decided to upgrade to tires with a diameter of $28.2$ inches without having onboard computer updated, how fast will the truck actually be travelling when the speedometer reads $75$ mph? Show solutions.

Comment: Is this homework, or are you thinking of buying bigger tires?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: With the standard tires, what is the angular velocity when the speedometer reads 75 mph? With the bigger tires, what is the linear velocity at this angular velocity?